# How to avoid building NaCl client for arm?

Tags: opencv, makefile, arm, google-nativeclient

I am trying to build a NaCl project that uses OpenCV. I am using part2 of getting_started code as a starting point. I read somewhere that OpenCV has not been ported to NaCl for arm architectures (or maybe I am wrong).
This is the output I got:

```
CXX  clang-newlib/Release/hello_tutorial_x86_32.o
LINK clang-newlib/Release/part2_unstripped_x86_32.nexe
VALIDATE clang-newlib/Release/part2_unstripped_x86_32.nexe
CXX  clang-newlib/Release/hello_tutorial_x86_64.o
LINK clang-newlib/Release/part2_unstripped_x86_64.nexe
VALIDATE clang-newlib/Release/part2_unstripped_x86_64.nexe
CXX  clang-newlib/Release/hello_tutorial_arm.o
hello_tutorial.cc:11:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' file not found
```

This is the Makefile:

```
VALID_TOOLCHAINS := clang-newlib

NACL_SDK_ROOT := $(NACL_SDK_ROOT)

TARGET = part2

include $(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/tools/common.mk

LIBS = ppapi_cpp ppapi pthread opencv_core z

CFLAGS = -Wall -std=gnu++11
SOURCES = hello_tutorial.cc

# Build rules generated by macros from common.mk:

$(foreach src,$(SOURCES),$(eval $(call COMPILE_RULE,$(src),$(CFLAGS))))

# The PNaCl workflow uses both an unstripped and finalized/stripped binary.
# On NaCl, only produce a stripped binary for Release configs (not Debug).
ifneq (,$(or $(findstring pnacl,$(TOOLCHAIN)),$(findstring Release,$(CONFIG))))
$(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET)_unstripped,$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
$(eval $(call STRIP_RULE,$(TARGET),$(TARGET)_unstripped))
else
$(eval $(call LINK_RULE,$(TARGET),$(SOURCES),$(LIBS),$(DEPS)))
endif

$(eval $(call NMF_RULE,$(TARGET),))
```

I would like to know how to avoid building my application for arm architectures. Is there anything else I can do to avoid that error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several variables to build the NaCl project. In short, NACL_ARCH has to be set properly, so I put the following line in my Makefile:

```
NACL_ARCH := x86_32 x86_64
```